# How to Create sub DataTable from an existing DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable`(dataTable1) that have 25-30 columns. I want to bind a `DataGridView` by creating a small DataTable (dataTable2) that will have few columns (may 5-10) from the existing DataTable.

So my main task is to create a `DataTable` with fewer columns from the existing one.

Here is the code what I have tried so for..

```
DataTable subDataTable()
{
   DataTable smallTable=new DataTable();

   smallTable =dataTable1;// dataTable1 is already filled with data
   smallTable.Columns.Remove("Column2");
   smallTable.Columns.Remove("Column5");
   smallTable.Columns.Remove("Column6");
   smallTable.Columns.Remove("Column13");
   smallTable.Columns.Remove("Column16");

   return smallTable;
}
```

Its working fine. But I'm looking if there any better way.

Comment: This code will not work because you effectively assign a variable `smallTable` to reference to `dataTable1` and you removing columns from `dataTable1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert your `DataTable` to `IEnumerable`,and `Select` necessary fields with linq like this:

```
var myValues = dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(x => new  { col1 = x["Column1"], col2 = x["Column2"]..});
dataGridView.DataSource = myValues;
```

Comment: Note that you have to add the using statement for `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work because you all you do is assign a variable `smallTable` with reference to `dataTable1` and you removing columns from your original table object

Linq is faster to write but here is what you want to do to understand your issue:

```
DataTable smallTable = dataTable1.Clone(); // Copy data structure
// Now you can remove your columns
smallTable.Columns.Remove("Column2");
......
foreach (var row in dataTable1.Rows) // iterate all rows 
{
    var newRow = smallTable.NewRow();
    foreach (var col in smallTable.Columns) // and iterate only needed columns
    {
        newRow[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName];
    }
}
```

This is pretty much what sugar-coated by Linq

Answer (score 1):

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dataTable1);
DataTable smallTable = dv.ToTable(true, new string[] { "Column2", "Column5"...});
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac2c7c95-66d6-4db6-a6fb-4dccd5fa701e/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-subtable-with-selected-columns-of-a-datatable?forum=adodotnetdataset

Tomer.